# How to test Azure storage lifecycle?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am currently using Azure Blobs. I want Azure to automatically delete some old data which are older then X number of days and prefix with wildcard.Such as

- myContainer/*/xxx.mp4

I only see this document [prefixMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: Is this link maybe helpfull? https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2018/10/using-logic-apps-to-delete-files-older-than-x-number-of-days-from-azure-blob-storage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure blob storage Life cycle management policy does not support wildcard in [prefixMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#rule-filters). You can see [this github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21571#issuecomment-452132524) and [this user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/41322538-filter-set-wildcard-match-in-storage-lifecycle-man).

To do that, you need write your own code to implement this logic. For example, you can use [azure function with timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp), or [logic app](https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2018/10/using-logic-apps-to-delete-files-older-than-x-number-of-days-from-azure-blob-storage/) as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can visit the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) document to know more about it